# Making a battery charger polarity-independent

Tags: voltage, batteries, analog, rectifier

I am trying to make a battery charger:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQdAfo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this configuration the polarity of the voltage doesn't matter the battery will be charged regardless of the input voltage (positive or negative). And the switch when closed changes the pulsed DC to DC if the input voltage is AC.

Is there a way to make the charger work with an installed battery in either polarity? (For a user who doesn't know how the battery should be put inside the battery charger, just as the polarity of the input voltage doesn't matter.)

Comment: I re-worded your last sentence because, frankly, I could not make sense of it for a while. Please review and make sure I got your meaning correct.

Comment: C2 (and the switch) is completely pointless. The battery itself is already a huge "capacitor", adding a much smaller one in parallel won't change a thing.

Comment: The schematic you show is NOT a battery charger. A battery charger controls the charge process, you show nothing that does this. Switching in the 1F capacitor when its voltage is low would result in large currents flowing out of the battery. When charged the supercap would smooth the battery current, but this is not an advantage and it does not increase the bridge conduction angle in any significant way.

Comment: It's probably much easier to design a charger that won't do anything if the battery is the wrong way round.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you wanted to badly enough you probably could manage to make a circuit that would at least usually work, presuming the battery you're trying to charger has at least a little "juice" left when it's placed in the charger. But the circuit would be quite a lot more complex, to put it midly.

The general idea would be to start with two diodes, connected to the battery in opposite directions:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOyfEo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we connect the battery we're going to charge on the left side, assuming it's still producing a little bit of output (greater than the forward voltage drop of a diode), we're going to get current flowing through one resistor, but not the other (i.e., depending on how it was connected, one diode will conduct, and the other won't).

To make that a practical circuit, we wouldn't just run that through a resistor though. We'd probably connect them up to something like an op-amp to get the resulting voltage to a usable logic level. We'd then use that logic-level signal through a driver to something like a relay that would connect the charge current to the battery terminals in the correct polarity (so, for example, a logic zero would connect negative on the bottom, positive on the top, and a logic one would connect positive on the bottom and negative on the top).

You probably also want a little bit of sequencing, so you'd connect the detection circuit, find which direction the battery was connected, store that result, disconnect the detection circuit, then connect the charging circuit.

With all that given, I probably wouldn't use hand-built circuitry. I'd probably use a microcontroller with a couple of A2D inputs, so you can handle the voltage detection, logic, and timing in a single chip. Add a relay driver, and this part of it is done.

As Jack Creasey has already pointed out, from there you probably need an actual battery charger. I know enough about them to recognize I'm not really competent to comment meaningfully on that part of the design though.